# Limit the harddrive storage of multiple Wordpress instances on one webserver

Tags: hosting

I´m hosting a webserver with multiple wordpress instances on it. Is there a possibility to limit the storage of each wordpress instance. There should be the possibility to change the storage easily per script.

Kind regards

I used google for searching but didn´t found anything.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make the restrictions on a web server level, not within WordPress itself.

You can restrict table size in the database or restrict folder sizes on the server itself.

Doing this however will break your site. If you restrict a folder to be no more than "X", then it can't process the PHP to render the page as there's no disk space available.  Similarly, if you restrict a table or database size (most web hosts restrict their MySQL databases to 1GB by default), there is no way to generate temporary sessions etc.

Check with your web host on the best-recommended practice for your particular environment - just be aware, the moment you put a restriction in place, you will break your site if you ever hit that limit.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer!

So it would be the best to limit the database? Or is the site also not working properly if the memory is used up? Isn´t wordpress printing out some error message if the memory is full? (I´m not sure, never had a full memory).

Comment: It wouldn't be a memory error as such, but if you have debug enabled it should dump an error to the screen. Otherwise, it would just be a blank white screen.